# How to use Protractor with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, testing, migration, protractor, angular

I use Protractor with Angular 1.x. I would like to migrate to Angular 2.0 step by step but I don't see Protractor [in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/).

Has protractor been dropped since Angular 2? Should I write my tests without using Protractor, using Jasmine instead (or others)?

Comment: Not at all, if you see in the [playground e2e examples](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/playground/e2e_test) most of them, if not all, use protractor.

Comment: To me, that qualifies as an answer @EricMartinez

Comment: Yes, it's a response part but it's TS and not JS pure and this files aren't an official status on Protractor's futur. But thank you, this is an initial response

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**You can test Angular 2 applications with `Protractor`** (starting from Protractor 2.5.0).

For [Protractor 5.0.0+](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500), you don't have to do anything specific, *Protractor will auto-detect the Angular version used in the application under test*.

For Protractor >= 2.5.0 and <= 4.0.14, you would only need to add `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true` to your config. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2bde92b3e745e09ad3876932b2d187365e9aaa31/spec/angular2Conf.js).

---

Note that several built-in Protractor matchers would not yet work with Angular2, see:

- [Protractor Angular 2 Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36201691/771848)

There is also that Protractor+Angular2 problem in Firefox (still unresolved), see:

- [Can't run Selenium via Protractor on Firefox after update to Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220948/cant-run-selenium-via-protractor-on-firefox-after-update-to-angular-2)

Comment: How does it work to test a website that is mixed angular 1.x and angular 2?  Is that a use-case that just isn't supported?

Comment: While you can use Protractor with Angular 2 at this time there are several key matchers which don't work, as explained on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201691/protractor-angular-2-failed-unknown-error-angular-is-not-defined

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500

This was changed in Protractor 5.0.0

Comment: @EricFrancis thanks for the update! I've updated the answer, let me know if you think we can add anything else here.