# How can I implement protractor in my Angular 2 app with webpack?

Tags: angular, protractor, angular2-services

I have never used protractor in Angular 2. Can anyone tell how can I implement protractor in Angular 2 with webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Protractor with Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541103/how-to-use-protractor-with-angular-2)

Comment: http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can test Angular 2 applications with `Protractor`** (starting from Protractor 2.5.0).

For [Protractor 5.0.0+](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500), you don't have to do anything specific, *Protractor will auto-detect the Angular version used in the application under test*.

For Protractor >= 2.5.0 and <= 4.0.14, you would only need to add `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true` to your config. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2bde92b3e745e09ad3876932b2d187365e9aaa31/spec/angular2Conf.js).

---

Note that several built-in Protractor matchers would not yet work with Angular2, see:

- [Protractor Angular 2 Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36201691/771848)

There is also that Protractor+Angular2 problem in Firefox (still unresolved), see:

- [Can't run Selenium via Protractor on Firefox after update to Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220948/cant-run-selenium-via-protractor-on-firefox-after-update-to-angular-2)

Please refer following link

[How to use Protractor with Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541103/how-to-use-protractor-with-angular-2/34467807#34467807)